# Show 'True' for each row where one column's value is at least 2 higher than another column's value

Tags: pandas

I know it's easy enough to show when a value is greater than another using

```
df = np.where(df['Column1'] > df['Column2'], True, False)
```

But how could I make it so only shows `True` if `Column 1` is at least 2 greater than `Column 2`?

For example:

```
if Column 1 = 500 and Column 2 = 499 then False 
But if Column 1 = 501 and Column 2 = 499 then True
```

Comment: Just do `df['new'] = df['Column 1'].add(2).gt(df['Column 2'])`

Comment: Thanks Mayank - I did put this in but the ValueError back was that 'Lengths must be Equal'. When comparing the columns just by greater than this didn't come up so why would it now?

Comment: Ideally you should edit the question to have a sample dataframe with expected output. Otherwise, it becomes really difficult for the community to help.